# MySQL creating derived table from union

Tags: mysql

Why won't this query run in MySQL? I'm trying to understand this so I can make a larger query with more complicated selects to fill in records, but I've torn it all down to the absolute basic building blocks and it still won't run.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(   
   (SELECT 'January' as col1 ) as t0     
    UNION 
   (SELECT 'December'  as col1 ) as t1
) as derivedTable
```

The error is *#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use* near 't1

I'm expecting it to look like:

```
col1
January
December
```

Comment: Does it need a FROM in the sub-selects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for all the subqueries. You can just write:

```
(
    SELECT 'January' AS col1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'December' AS col1
) AS derivedTable
```

I assume this is being used as a subquery in a larger query (e.g. to do a `LEFT JOIN` to get results for every month).

Comment: You're correct but I can't get my complicated query to work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47757420/adding-union-to-a-complex-select-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

you must change your script to:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(   
   (SELECT 'January' AS col1 ) 
    UNION 
   (SELECT 'December'  AS col1 ) 
) AS derivedTable
```