# Adding UNION to a complex SELECT in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I would like help adding a UNION to get all the months to a query. I tried adding union in a bunch of spots but just can't get it right. 
[image]

```
SELECT MONTH(FirstPublishedToPortal) AS theMonth,
   YEAR(FirstPublishedToPortal) AS theYear,
   MONTHNAME(FirstPublishedToPortal) AS theMonthName,
   COUNT(DISTINCT PONum) AS POCount,

   SUM(unconfirmedEmailSent) AS unconfirmedEmailsSent,
   ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PONum)
     FROM POFlags
     WHERE unconfirmedEmailSent = 0
     AND MONTH(FirstPublishedToPortal) = theMonth
     AND YEAR(FirstPublishedToPortal) = theYear
     AND VendorNum = '2222'
   ) AS onTimeConfirmed,

   SUM(lateEmailSent) AS lateEmailsSent,
   ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PONum)
     FROM POFlags
     WHERE lateEmailSent = 0
     AND MONTH(FirstPublishedToPortal) = theMonth
     AND YEAR(FirstPublishedToPortal) = theYear
     AND VendorNum = '2222'
   ) AS onTimePOCount

FROM POFlags

WHERE VendorNum = '2222'
   AND FirstPublishedToPortal >= '2017-01-08'

GROUP BY theYear DESC, theMonth DESC
ORDER BY FirstPublishedToPortal DESC
```

Where do the union clauses go in this query? 
I think there needs to be something like the following code but I don't understand where to put it to work correctly with the GROUP BY or ORDER BY.

```
(SELECT 1, null, 'January', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
UNION 
(SELECT 2, null, 'February', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
UNION 
(SELECT 3, null, 'March', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
.    
.
(SELECT 12, null, 'December, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

[SQL FIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/458808/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a left join based on a nested query with union.

Use Coalesce to apply your default values.

Move where condition on join clause

*warning, 2017 is hardcoded*

Something like this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/458808/27

```
SELECT
    all_month.nMonth AS theMonth, 
    coalesce(YEAR(FirstPublishedToPortal),2017) AS theYear,
    all_month.sMonth AS theMonthName,
    coalesce(COUNT(DISTINCT PONum),0) AS POCount,

    coalesce(SUM(unconfirmedEmailSent),0) AS unconfirmedEmailsSent,
    coalesce(( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PONum)
       FROM POFlags
       WHERE unconfirmedEmailSent = 0
         AND MONTH(FirstPublishedToPortal) = theMonth
         AND YEAR(FirstPublishedToPortal) = theYear
         AND VendorNum = '2222'
    ),0) AS onTimeConfirmed,

    coalesce(SUM(lateEmailSent),0) AS lateEmailsSent,
    coalesce(( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PONum)
       FROM POFlags
       WHERE lateEmailSent = 0
         AND MONTH(FirstPublishedToPortal) = theMonth
         AND YEAR(FirstPublishedToPortal) = theYear
         AND VendorNum = '2222'
     ),0) AS onTimePOCount
FROM (
     (SELECT 1 nMonth, 'January' sMonth)   UNION ALL
     (SELECT 2 nMonth, 'February' sMonth ) UNION ALL
     (SELECT 3 nMonth, 'March' sMonth )    UNION ALL
     (SELECT 4 nMonth, 'April' sMonth )    UNION ALL
     (SELECT 5 nMonth, 'May' sMonth )      UNION ALL
     (SELECT 6 nMonth, 'June' sMonth )     UNION ALL
     (SELECT 7 nMonth, 'July' sMonth )     UNION ALL
     (SELECT 8 nMonth, 'August' sMonth )   UNION ALL
     (SELECT 9 nMonth, 'September' sMonth) UNION ALL
     (SELECT 10 nMonth, 'October' sMonth ) UNION ALL
     (SELECT 11 nMonth, 'November' sMonth )UNION ALL    
     (SELECT 12 nMonth, 'December' sMonth)
     ) all_month left join POFlags on
         MONTH(FirstPublishedToPortal)=nMonth and
         VendorNum = '2222' and
         FirstPublishedToPortal >= '2017-01-08'
GROUP BY
    theYear DESC, nMonth DESC
ORDER BY
    nMonth DESC
```

Another way exist using a global union between your orginal result and the default value, but this method require a second group by...

Comment: This works wonderfully. I had trouble understanding where to put the UNION selects. And using COALESCE for default values--I never thought of that! Since I can build this query at run time, I can pass the year based on some parameter passed to my PHP script-- so no problem there. Thank you!

Comment: How I solved the default hardcoded year problem since I only needed one year's worth of data and had some variables available in my script:
 `COALESCE(YEAR(FirstPublishedToPortal), IF(nMonth > " . $cutoff_month . ", " . $prev_year . ", " . $cutoff_year . ") )  AS theYear,`

Comment: Using PHP, it's a simple solution ;-). With SQL only it's a little more complexe.